# Does MySql support extproc?

Tags: mysql, database, xp-cmdshell

I just want to know if MySql supports low-level database functions such as xp_cmdshell and extproc. I know xp_cmdshell is not supported for MySql due to security policies but what about extproc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the closest thing to extproc for MySQL is [ProxySQL](http://www.proxysql.com). But it's not really a very close match, architecturally.

If you develop plugins or user-defined functions (UDFs)<sup>†</sup> for MySQL, they run as shared libraries (DLLs) in the mysqld process.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/writing-plugins.html say:

> A [UDF/server plugin] contains code that becomes part of the running server, so when you write a UDF, you are bound by any and all constraints that apply to writing server code.

In other words, effectively no security, and these compiled objects  have total access to everything in that process. You are responsible for not installing plugins or UDFs that would compromise security.

<sup>†</sup> Note that UDFs are not the same as [MySQL Stored Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-routines.html). UDFs are written in C/C++. Stored functions are written in MySQL's implementation of ANSI SQL procedure language.

Comment: Oh! Thank you for the reply, I finally got the answer I wanted. Thanks!